# What should be adminclient-congs.conf in kafka acl authorization

Tags: apache-kafka, acl, sasl

I am running kafka on windows. I have used SASL/PLAIN mechanism for authentication and SSL for encryption. I have to enable Authorization but I have no idea what the file "adminclient-congs.conf" should have in the command

```
kafka-acls --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --command-config adminclient-configs.conf --add --allow-principal User:alice --allow-principal User:fred --allow-host host-1 --allow-host host-2 --operation read --operation write --topic finance-topic
```

I looks like this file should contain credentials of the root user but I don't really know the format and how to make root user when using SASL_SSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration file needs to contain the same settings you use with regular Kafka clients from https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#adminclientconfigs

The file must use the "properties" format:

`config-name=value`

With SASL and SSL, you need at least:

```
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule \
    required username="USER" password="PASSWORD";
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

You may need more settings depending on your exact cluster configuration

Comment: Thanks this works but gives warning "The configuration ssl.trustore.location was supplied but isn't known config in AdminClientConfig" and when I remove this configuration it won't work because ssl is also enabled. Any idea why this warning?

Comment: These warnings appear on the latest version, you can ignore them

Comment: Do you know where to find logs for such authentication via AdminClientConfig when the shell script (e.g. `kafka-topics.sh`) with passed information just hangs after printing the warning `The configuration <...> was supplied but isn't known config in AdminClientConfig...` for all provided properties?